# history-search-end doesn't work

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, command-history, line-editor

My `~/.zshrc`:

```
setopt histignoredups
autoload -U history-search-end
zle -N history-beginning-search-backward-end history-search-end
zle -N history-beginning-search-forward-end history-search-end
bindkey "^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward-end
bindkey "^[[B" history-beginning-search-forward-end
```

I want up arrow to fill the last command line that matches the command line typed so far,

```
dotnet build
dotnet bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/MyProg.dll
dotnet build
dotnet bin<UP ARROW>
```

should fill in `dotnet bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/MyProg.dll`.

However, with the `~/.zshrc` I currently have, it fills in `dotnet build`.

Looks like it only works up to the first space.

How can I make the up arrow select the last command line that matches the command line typed so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL,DR:

```
bindkey "^[OA" history-beginning-search-backward-end
bindkey "^[OB" history-beginning-search-forward-end
```

---

Does your terminal actually send `^[[A` for <kbd>Up</kbd>? Mine sends `^[OA`. With your `.zshrc`:

```
darkstar% bindkey | grep '\^\[.A'
"^[OA" up-line-or-history
"^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward-end
```

Pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> sends `^[OA` which has its default binding and recalls the previous line. It's just a coincindence that the previous line starts with the same word. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> recalls the previous line starting with `dotnet bin` as desired.

To check what your terminal sends for a function or cursor key, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then the key or key chord. Note that full-screen applications often use a different terminal mode from command-line applications where some keys send different escape sequences (Application Cursor Keys). `^[[A` is the usual command-line escape sequence for <kbd>Up</kbd>, `^[OA` is the usual full-screen escape sequence.

Comment: It seems to be inconsistent. Some of my terminal's tabs are `^[[A` and some are `^[OA`. Do you know why this might be? Terminal.app on macOS